# What was May's plan with Agent 33?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

I just watched the episode where

> Ward accidentally killed Agent 33/Kara

and I think I missed something.

As far as I know, May knew that Kara was listening on the radio. She faked an order to all agents to gather at a specific location, seemingly to trick Kara to go there.

Then we see Kara, disguised as May, running into Ward who shoots her, thinking she is the real May.

Here's what I do not understand:

- What was May's plan? Did she plan that Kara would run into Ward? How could
  she know he was there? How could she know Kara would be disguised as her? If not, what else was her plan?
- Why did Kara disguise as May, knowing Ward is running around looking for May?
- Why did Ward shoot without hesitation, knowing that Kara often disguises herself as May?

Comment: My thought would be... at worst, slows them down sorting out friend or foe.  At best... well, I think May got it.

Comment: Ok downvoters. Please help me to elaborate. What is wrong? I'm not asking for opinions. I asked if I missed something. "No, you missed nothing, it was pure luck, coincidence and stupidity of Kara and Ward and May just planned to trick Kara to go there to catch her there." would be a valid answer. :-)

Comment: Erm. Am I supposed to close the question because there seems to be no answer?

Comment: @Hothie Not at all! There's nothing wrong with having an unanswered question; someone could come along at any time and answer it. If you want to draw more attention to it, you could always add a bounty ...

Comment: My understanding was that she wanted Kara to fake herself as May to ambush the meeting, and for Ward to then kill Kara thinking she was May.

Answer (score 2):

May's plan was twofold: one, she knew Kara could impersonate her. Second, she knew Ward personally had a hate on for her. She also knew, at the time, that Ward and Kara were in separate locations.

She gave them both different bait with the same message: by telling the other agents she was coming, she presented Kara with an opening to infiltrate the other SHIELD agents by impersonating May. But May also knew Ward couldn't pass up an opportunity to kill her (May) himself, and she'd just told him where she was going to be.

It was based on knowing her opponents better than the opponents knew each other. She knew Kara wouldn't pass up an opportunity to infiltrate and gain the advantage, and that Ward would be so blinded by his hate that he wouldn't think about the possibility. Kara, on the other hand, didn't realize the depth of hatred Ward had for May and that he'd probably shoot as soon as he saw her face without ensuring it was May he was shooting at.

May was taking a gamble, but it was a reasonable one.

Answer (score 0):

She knew where Ward was because there were "no communications fro0m agents on the south side." She ordered all of them there and to "stand down when you see my face." Ward killing her was the plan.